# Babel plugin for react state outside of constructor

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

What babel plugin do i need to be able to use the following syntax?

```
class Temp extends React.Component {
    ---> state = {
             test: '',
         }

        ....rest
}
```

i have `babel-core`, `babel-reset-env` and `babel-preset-react` in my dev dependencies and my `.babelrc` has:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env", "react"
  ]
}
```

While playing around on the babel site, i noticed that that syntax was being controlled by `babel-stage-2`. I couldn't find a reference to it in `creat-react-app` so i wanted to know how to actually enable that in my project.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin is called [transform-class-properties.](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!